# Mod_quotatab for a global quota

Tags: proftpd

Is there a way to use `mod_quotatab` with proftpd and have a quota that extends over every user as a total, instead of each user individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  For this, you would use the "all" quota type, as opposed to "user", "group", or "class".  The "all" quota type is the [last type looked up](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab.html#QuotaLookup), assuming no other applicable quotas are found.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Better late than never! This isn't applicable to me anymore, but I'm fairly certain this would do what I'd need.